# Reading binary data into std::string c++

Tags: c++, string, binary

I am trying to read data from binary file to an std::string.Here is what I have tried at first.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    fstream file("output.bin" , ios::out | ios::binary | ios::in);
    string my_str(5, '\0');
    file.read(my_str.c_str(), 5);
    cout << "String = " << my_str<< endl ;
}
```

And the compiler gave the error :

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘std::basic_istream<char>::char_type* {aka char*}’ [-fpermissive]
  file.read(my_str.c_str(), 5);
```

As far as I understand, c_str() returns a const pointer which cannot be used in read method, so I changed my approach a little bit(which you can see below). Is there a better way to do this ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    fstream file("output.bin" , ios::out | ios::binary | ios::in);
    string my_str(5, '\0');
    char buffer[6];
    file.read(buffer, 5);
    buffer[5] = '\0';
    my_str = string(buffer);

    cout << "String = " << my_str<< endl ;
}
```

ps : forgive me if I could not make myself clear, this is my first time here :)

Comment: I would use `std::vector<char>` or `std::vector<uint8_t>` instead of `std::string`

Comment: I could never understand why people use `std::string` for binary data. Keep in mind that this container's `value_type` is `char`, which may lead to problems related to sign extension (for example, think about what the result of `my_str[3] == 0x95` will be). You might want to use `std::vector<std::uint8_t>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++11, the way to get a non-`const` pointer to the string's data is:

```
file.read(&my_str[0], 5);
```

C++17 will introduce non-`const` `data()` for this as well:

```
file.read(my_str.data(), 5);
```

Comment: These quirks really make C++ great. A convenient non-const method to get the internal string buffer will be added 35 years late.

Comment: Just to be sure, the size of my_str before calling the read method should be greater than or equal to 5 , right ? @Barry

Comment: @baris_esmer Of course. All the usual caveats apply.

Answer (score 2):

another way, using standard algorithms:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    fstream file("output.bin" , ios::out | ios::binary | ios::in);

    auto my_str = string();

    copy_n(istream_iterator<char>(file), 
           5, 
           std::back_inserter(my_str));

    cout << "String = " << my_str<< endl ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` is specially designed to work with strings and with c-style strings as well, so this fact will work against you in this situation. For example your code:

```
char buffer[6];
file.read(buffer, 5);
buffer[5] = '\0';
my_str = string(buffer);
```

what is wrong with it? You are reading binary data and who guarantees that there won't be '\0' byte there? You can fix it by:

```
my_str = string(buffer,5);
```

but this shows the point - `std::string` as a buffer is not a good choice. So you better use `std::vector<char>` or even better `std::vector<uint8_t>` which has method `data()` but will not implicitly convert from c-string, output to `std::ostream` etc.